# Eigenvector associated to the highest eigenvalue

Tags: matlab, pca, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I have a question that is more theoretical than practical. If I perform PCA on a matrix (in MATLAB) I obtain in output a matrix *coeff* and a matrix *score* that represent respectively loadings and principal component scores. I wonder if the first column of the score matrix is the eigenvector associated with the highest eigenvalue or, in other words, if it is the leading eigenvector.

Comment: The documentation will explain this: https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pca.html#namevaluepairarguments — In shift: by default `pca` uses SVD, not eigenvalue decomposition. If you specify you want eigenvalue decomposition, then yes, the columns in the coefficient matrix are in order of importance.

Comment: @Cris Luengo, thank you for your answer. You said that with `eig` algorithm the columns in the **coefficient** matrix are in order of importance, but what about the **score** matrix?

Comment: The order should match for all outputs. The coefficients are always in order of importance, I meant to say that only using the `eig` mode do you get “the first column of the score matrix is the eigenvector associated with the highest eigenvalue”. Otherwise it’s the largest singular value. Do use the default singular value mode though, it’s more robust.

Comment: If I use default SVD, is there a method to extract the leading eigenvector?

Comment: SVD extracts singular values and singular vectors. They are also sorted by importance, the first one is the most important. They're not eigenvectors, but they are comparable.